# CSS3 : Flex display and overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow, flexbox

I'm having trouble using CSS3 flex display and overflow.
I'd like a box to be "y-scrollable" if contents overflow on y-axis and "x-overflowed" if content overflows on x-axis.

I found [this codepen](http://codepen.io/simurai/pen/dvklJ) illustrating how to set the box y-scrollable and I forked [this one](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wbGtC) to illustrate my problem.
As you can see (using Chrome), a x-scrollbar is added even if overflow-x is set to visible. I hoped content would overflow upon the y-scrollbar and be visible without x-scrollbar...

Any solution ?

The base HTML code is

```
    <ul>
        <li><div>Item</div></li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
```

The base CSS code is

```
ul {
  flex: 1;  
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

And, to make trouble, replace by

```
ul {
  flex: 1;  
  min-height: 0;
  overflow-x: visible ;
  overflow-y: auto;

}

div{
    background-color : red ;
    width : 150% ;
}
```

For make it really revealant, add

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: hsl(200,100%,90%);
}

li { padding: 20px; }

li:nth-child(odd) { background: hsl(200,100%,85%); }

header, footer { padding: 20px; background: hsl(0,0%,70%); }

body {
    display: flex;

    /* doesn't work without prefix */
    -webkit-flex-flow: column; 
    flex-flow: column;

    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    background: hsl(0,0%,80%);
}

html { height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Your question is well explained, it will be better if you also post your relevant code here, if the link dies in future, your question wont be useful for future visitors..

Comment: Here it is ! Thanks !

Comment: I'll help you out to retag so that you get some views

Comment: This has nothing to do with flexbox. I'm pretty sure you can't have both visible and scroll/auto together (how is it supposed to look anyway?).

Comment: Thanks BoltClock♦ ! As you said, there is no link with flexbox.
[This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209545/css-overflow-yvisible-overflow-xscroll) helped me resolving my problem ! Thanks' again !

Answer (score 0):

I could be reading this wrong, but if you're not wanting there to be a horizontal scroll bar, then you can set `overflow-x: hidden;` and it should be okay.