# Handsontable popup autocomplete editor gets cut off at horrizontal scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, handsontable

i have an autocomplete feature on all columns.  as you can see in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tomkast/ub5vbsdp/  the autocompelte editor gets cut off by the horizontal scrollbar.

```
some code required by stackoverflow to post the jsfiddle link
```

maybe the problem is what is described here: http://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

i have been working way too long on this problem (so says my boss) so if you have any idea/ jquery work-arounds i would love to know...

Comment: -1 for lack of research??  try 72 hours of research...  ..not apparent because i did not include the code here?  adding some gratuitous portion of the js code here seemed, well, gratuitous so i left the code on jsfiddle -- is that what the -1 is about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have to do a workaround to make it work, but it is possible. As you can see in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209545/css-overflow-yvisible-overflow-xscroll), you need to have `overflow: auto;` in parent, and `position: fixed;` in child.

This may be a problem later, but no other `position` setting works in this scenario, so let's hope it won't be. [Here's the working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ub5vbsdp/6/)

Comment: unreal.  it works perfectly.  thank you so much.  i offer you my 100% gratitude.

Comment: one more issue here.  i need to compensate for the scrolling of a viewport-div.  i tried adding top and left to the autocompleteEditor css, and then using jquery to update those values dynamically, but i ran into all kinds of problems.  It seems I need to understand how autocompleteEditor is positioned.  As we left it, the CSS is position:fixed; and there is no top or left.  So how is HOT moving it around the screen?  Once I understand that, I can use the beforeKeyDown: function (e) {} and subtract $('#content')[0].scrollTop which was working well....

Comment: for anyone that is interested, i found a div that is a parent of the autocompelteEditor $('.handsontableInputHolder') which has an absolute top and left to work with.  But simply grabbing those values and assigning them to the top/left of autocompleteEditor with an init callback is breaking some other positioning logic...  something like beforeKeyDown: function (e) { $('.autocompleteEditor').css('top', ($('.handsontableInputHolder')[0].offsetTop - $('#content')[0].scrollTop) + 'px');}